# Parse and share obj resources in module

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I wanted to know if its good practice to use it like following since I used a global field **cacheObj**
I need to parse the data and share it between other modules,any module can take any property but only the first module which called to this parser is responsible to provide the data to parse(I need to do this parse just once and share properties in different modules)

This code is from  other SO post and I want to use it

```
var Parser = require('myParser'),
    _ = require('lodash');

var cacheObj; // <-- singleton, will hold value and will not be reinitialized on myParser function call

function myParser(data) {
    if (!(this instanceof myParser)) return new myParser(data);
    if (!_.isEmpty(cacheObj)) { 
        this.parsedData = cacheObj; 
    } else {
        this.parsedData = Parser.parse(data);
        cacheObj = this.parsedData; 
    }
}

myParser.prototype = {
    //remove `this.cacheObj`
    getPropOne: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propOne;
    },

    getPropTwo: function () {
        return this.parsedData.propTwo;
    }
};

module.exports = myParser;
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it would work, also 'cachedObj' is not going to be set as a global variable. This module will be wrapped up, so all variables you declare will remain in the context of the module and not attached to the global object, so 'myParser' will be just a closure of 'cachedObj'

Comment: Thanks, I know that it works , checked it:) my question is whether this is a good practice to use this variable like this? 2. this is hoisting and not global variable?

Answer (score 1):

It kindda looks like the [Context Object](http://corej2eepatterns.com/ContextObject.htm) pattern, which is used for maintaining state and for sharing information. Some consider it a bad practice and prefer Singleton when it comes to share the object between layers, but if suites your case (in the same module) - my advice is to use it.

*UPDATE*

The main reason why you shouldn't use ContextObject through your layes is because it binds all sub-systems together( one object is referencing everything else). While Singleton is not just for creating objects, it is also services as access point that can be loaded by the corresponding sub-system. Having a Singleton represent every service access point allows for seamless vertical integration of cooperating components/modules. Simple code example:

Singleton:

```
 // returns the "global" time
 var time = Clock.getInstance().getTime();
```

Context object:

```
 // allows different timezones to coexist within one application
 var time = context.getTimezoneOffset().getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks 1+ and how would you do that with singleton(since I thogt this is singleton already)  can you provide example with my code how would you do it?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Key difference is that Context obj is created for every request, once you've parsed the data. Later just pass this obj to every horizontal functionality that rely on it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks can you please give example how would you imlement my example as singlton?